# Insert to and select from

Tags: t-sql, ssis

I am preparing Microsoft SSIS Certification. In the exercice Practice_5-Loading Data: the code provided by the training kit Exam 70-463 doesn't work.

Error message:

> Msg 121, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 The select list for the INSERT
>   statement contains more items than the insert list. The number of
>   SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

Error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

Need some help.

Comment: Error message is self explanatory. Quick internet search will provide you a solution.

Comment: If you don't post any code that leads to this error message we can't help you, other than @AB_87 told you, "google the error message".

Comment: INSERT INTO dbo.Customers
(CustomerDwKey, CustomerKey, FullName,
EmailAddress, Birthdate, MaritalStatus,
Gender, Education, Occupation,
City, StateProvince, CountryRegion)
SELECT
NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.SeqCustomerDwKey AS CustomerDwKey,
C.CustomerKey,
C.FirstName, C.LastName AS FullName,
C.EmailAddress, C.BirthDate, C.MaritalStatus,
C.Gender, C.EnglishEducation, C.EnglishOccupation,
G.City, G.StateProvinceName, G.EnglishCountryRegionName
FROM AdventureWorksDW2012.dbo.DimCustomer AS C
INNER JOIN AdventureWorksDW2012.dbo.DimGeography AS G
ON C.GeographyKey = G.GeographyKey;
GO

Comment: you are inserting `C.FirstName` for `FullName` and then you also have `C.LastName AS FullName`. Fix this first.

Comment: the code is the exact copy from the answer book so it can't be wrong. I think it is when creating the table, I understand the structure of tables I created myself is wrong. Yesterday I tried to implement tables with the answers book and the load works perfectly. Now I have to know what wrong with my table. Tanks for your advices

Answer (score -1):

Concatinate the two columns (C.FirstName, C.LastName) as fullname.

Thanks
Sasi

Answer (score -1):

I finally find the problem. they were different structure between tables I created and the loading from table... primary key was different and 'curent flag' data type need to have default value set to 1.

thanks for your help

sagbo